# Change timer at runtime c#

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, dispatchertimer

Iv'e created a timer using dispatcher time :

```
time = new DispatcherTimer();
time.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 80);
```

and I use it for the speed of an object.Each tick the objects moves 10 pixels.
I would like to know how to increase the speed of the object without changing the pixels it moves each tick, meaning I want to make the timer itself faster during run time every 10 seconds or so.
Is there a way I can do it?Ive tried making a variable speed=0 and increasing it each time I count 10 and then

```
time.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 80-speed);
```

but The object stayed in the same speed.So do I have to make my own timer class instead of using the built in dispatcher time, if so how do I do that?or is there another solution for this?

Comment: Did you restart the timer (stop/start - or disable/enable)?

Comment: Alternatively, have the timer fire more often right from the get go - but earlier (in time) just have the timer do nothing for some of the ticks.

Comment: 80 milliseconds is very small value for the Interval of a DispatcherTimer anyway. Choose a larger interval with a larger moving distance. Then try again.

Comment: If I restart the time wouldn't it stop and then continue?

Comment: In general, animating the position of an object is usually implemented with a fixed update cycle time interval, but a variable length speed vector.

Comment: Clemens, I found that the lower I set the number at the end the faster my object goes.

Comment: Well, sure it does that. Think about adding 10 pixels 10 times per second or 20 times per second. Speed is distance per time. What you call speed is actually a time interval, and inversely propertional to distance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `DispatcherTimer` is not your best ally for this task. The class is by no means designed to execute actions at precise intervals.

I'll try to better explain myself: even if the `DispatcherTimer`, as its name suggests, dispatches actions timely and with a great precision, the dispatched actions will be queued and then executed when the underlying `GUI` thread decides to process them.

Normally, a `GUI` thread has a resolution of around `8ms` (it's an approximation, but I don't think we need to measure this right now)... and you are using a starting `Interval` of `80ms` that is going to decrease over time until it probably goes beyond that tolerance limit of `8ms` or so. In the meanwhile, you are also repainting your interface (or part of it) over and over and this impacts the performance and the responsiveness of the `GUI` even more: if the `GUI` thread is busy repainting and that requires more than the `Interval` value to be accomplished, the next dispatched action will be processed only once the `GUI` thread completes the undergoing task.

If you need a more precise scheduling, avoiding hangings / losses of responsiveness / delayed actions, you need to use a timer class that runs in background like `System.Threading.Timer` (google for `SyncronizationContext`, that would be helpful) or `System.Timers.Timer`.

On the top of that, never play with intervals when showing a change in speed. Work with a fixed interval and increase/decrease the movement "size" in pixels. You should be able to calculate the delta without problems. Just to make things clearer: *if I want to slow that the speed of an object doubled, I don't half the timer interval that draws the object, but I double the amount of pixels my object traverses at each step*.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with choosing a DispatcherTimer for animations at reasonable time intervals. Updating the positions of objects in a simple game (as OP does) doesn't need to be done more than 10 times per seconds, i.e. every 100 ms. DispatcherTimer is well capable of doing that, plus you don't need to care for invoking anything in the UI thread.

Comment: However, if you want to implement a realistic physics animation in WPF, you would go with [Per-Frame Animation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/property-animation-techniques-overview#per-frame-animation-bypass-the-animation-and-timing-system) instead of any Timer stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace CQRS_and_EventSourcing
{
    internal class Program
    {
        //CQRS = command query responsibility segregation
        //CQS= command query separation

        //COMMAND

        public class PersonStroge
        {
            Dictionary<int, Person> people;
        }

        public class Person
        {
            public int UniqueId;
            public int age;
            EventBroker broker;

            public Person(EventBroker broker)
            {
                this.broker = broker;
                broker.Commands += BrokerOnCommands;
                broker.Queries += BrokeronQueries;
            }

            private void BrokeronQueries(object sender, Query query)
            {
                var ac = query as AgeQuery;
                if (ac != null && ac.Target == this)
                {
                    ac.Result = age;
                }
            }

            private void BrokerOnCommands(object sender, Command command)
            {
                var cac = command as ChangeAgeCommand;
                if (cac != null && cac.Target == this)
                {
                    if (cac.Register)
                        broker.AllEvents.Add(new AgeChangedEvent(this, age, cac.Age));
                    age = cac.Age;
                }
            }
            public bool CanVote => age >= 16;
        }
        public class EventBroker
        {
            //1. All events that happened.
            public IList<Event> AllEvents = new List<Event>();
            //2. Commands
            public event EventHandler<Command> Commands;
            //3. Query
            public event EventHandler<Query> Queries;

            public void Command(Command c)
            {
                Commands?.Invoke(this, c);
            }

            public T Query<T>(Query q)
            {
                Queries?.Invoke(this, q);
                return (T)q.Result;
            }

            public void UndoLast()
            {
                var e = AllEvents.LastOrDefault();
                var ac = e as AgeChangedEvent;
                if (ac != null)
                {
                    Command(new ChangeAgeCommand(ac.Target, ac.OldValue) { Register = false });
                    AllEvents.Remove(e);
                }
            }
        }
        public class Query
        {
            public object Result;
        }
        public class AgeQuery : Query
        {
            public Person Target;
        }
        public class Command : EventArgs
        {
            public bool Register = true;
        }
        public class ChangeAgeCommand : Command
        {
            public Person Target;
            //public int TargetId;
            public int Age;

            public ChangeAgeCommand(Person target, int age)
            {
                Target = target;
                Age = age;
            }
        }

        public class Event
        {
            //backtrack
        }
        public class AgeChangedEvent : Event
        {
            public Person Target;
            public int OldValue, NewValue;

            public AgeChangedEvent(Person target, int oldValue, int newValue)
            {
                Target = target;
                OldValue = oldValue;
                NewValue = newValue;
            }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"Age changed from {OldValue} to {NewValue}";
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var eb = new EventBroker();
            var p = new Person(eb);

            eb.Command(new ChangeAgeCommand(p, 123));

            foreach (var e in eb.AllEvents)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            //int age;

            //age = eb.Query<int>(new AgeQuery { Target = p });
            //Console.WriteLine(age);

            //eb.UndoLast();
            //foreach (var e in eb.AllEvents)
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine(e);
            //}

            //age = eb.Query<int>(new AgeQuery { Target = p });
            //Console.WriteLine(age);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

İf you couldnt make look at this repository;
[1]:https://github.com/kYasinAblay/DNesteruk.Additional.Lectures/blob/master/CQRS_and_EventSourcing/Program.cs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).